# How to make associative array in Yii2?

Tags: php, arrays, yii, yii2

I would like to make associative array using foreach to use in Yii 2 dropdownlist.
My goal is to make array like following using foreach-

```
$array= [
  ['id' => '123', 'name' => 'abc'],
  ['id' => '124', 'name' => 'def'],
];
```

And then I want to use them using Yii 2 ArrayHelper::map().

```
$result = ArrayHelper::map($array, 'id', 'name');
```

How do I make the array using foreach?

Answer (score 2):

Yii way to build items for drop-down list is exactly as you described, using `ArrayHelper::map()`:

```
$items = ArrayHelper::map($array, 'id', 'name');
```

You don't need to use `foreach` here, just pass results of `ActiveQuery` as array:

```
$array = YourModel::find()->all();
```

**Update:**

> Thanks. But here, I am actually calculating custom value for 'name'
>   and for that reason I want to use foreach to generate the array after
>   the calculation

You definetely need to add this information to the question, but anyway, you can use the `ArrayHelper` for that too. Take a look at `toArray` method. It can be used for both object / array of objects. After processing with this method you can use `map`.

**Official docs:**

- [ArrayHelper::map()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper.html#map%28%29-detail)
- [ArrayHelper::toArray()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper.html#toArray%28%29-detail)

Comment: Thanks. But here, I am actually calculating custom value for 'name' and for that reason I want to use foreach to generate the array after the calculation.

Comment: Updated the question with information how to handle that.

Comment: by using your solution can i convert  `array(3) { [0]=> array(3) { ["slab_start"]=> string(1) "1" ["slab_end"]=> string(3) "100" ["rate"]=> string(2) "10" } [1]=> array(3) { ["slab_start"]=> string(3) "101" ["slab_end"]=> string(3) "150" ["rate"]=> string(2) "12" } [2]=> array(3) { ["slab_start"]=> string(3) "151" ["slab_end"]=> NULL ["rate"]=> string(2) "14" } }`  to `[100 => 10, 150 => 12, PHP_INT_MAX => 14];` for `N` number of records?